# JUNIT Test for partial update with java springboot mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, junit, mocking

Hello I am new to JUnit test and Mockito and my question is how can I write a unit test for this custom partial update method in my `customArticleRepository`, which has no return parameter? 
I have a POJO object named `Article` and I would like to partially update it. The REST endpoint PUT get a DTO Object `Classification Mask` with the specific updated value as request body, call the Service layer `ArticleService`, which call my `CustomArticleRepository` method.

this is my Article object

```
public class Article {

private String id;
@Field("_cls")
private String inheritance;
private String title;
private Date published;
private String content;
private String link;

private String summary;
private String description;
private Date updated;
private String primary;
private String[] secondary;
private String category;
private String[] categories;
private String person;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
private Date deleted_date;

private Boolean is_new;

private Boolean edited;
private Aws aws;
```

this is my DTO Object

```
public class ClassificationMask {
private String id;
private String title;
private String content;
private String primary;
private String[] secondary;

private Float sentiment_positive;
private Float sentiment_negative;
private Float sentiment_neutral;
private Float sentiment_mixed;

private String category;
private String person;
private Boolean is_new;
private Datasource datasource;
```

and this is my partialupdate method in the repository

```
public void partialUpdateMask(String id, ClassificationMask articleUpdate) {
    Query query = new Query(where("id").is(id));
    Update update = new Update();

    if(articleUpdate.getPrimary() !=null) { update.set("primary", articleUpdate.getPrimary()); }
    if(articleUpdate.getSecondary() !=null){ update.set("secondary", articleUpdate.getSecondary());}
    if(articleUpdate.getCategory() !=null){ update.set("category", articleUpdate.getCategory());}
    if(articleUpdate.getPerson() !=null){ update.set("person",articleUpdate.getPerson());}
    if(articleUpdate.getIs_new() !=null){ update.set("is_new",articleUpdate.getIs_new()); }

    update.set("edited",true);
    mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query,update ,Article.class);
}
```

Comment: Is Update your class?

Comment: @Renato no it is a class from springboot, here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Update.html

Answer (score 1):

Testing void method we could have:

1. Method that modifies the status of the object under test: so you can verify that the state of the sut is consistent with your aspectative
2. Method doesn't modify the status of the SUT but, for example, writes data on the DB so you can verify that your DAO is invoked

This is the second case and you can have something like this:

```
Mockito.verify(mongoTemplate).updateFirst(query, update, Article.class);
```

In this manner you're testing that

1. the method really calls updateFirst
2. the method calss updateFirst using the right parameters